# Native MP3s not playing in iOS 8 when behind .htaccess

Tags: ios, .htaccess

I have been serving some mp3s to a small community for years just by linking straight to the MP3 and letting the device's browser handle the playback. All worked fine until users updated their iPhones to iOS 8. Now playing MP3's natively doesn't work. After lots of testing I seem to have narrowed it down to the use of .htaccess.

Here are two identical directories with the same mp3 and [directory listing software](http://www.directorylister.com/) in them. But one is password protected (U:music P:access).

**Normal:** http://danielmee.com/dl/

**Secured:** http://danielmee.com/dl-secure/

I've also tried using a [JS player](http://mediaelementjs.com) which also broke once behind the secure directory.
What changed in iOS 8 to disable MP3 playback and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I should add that the problem still exists when everything is stripped down to just the file.

Comment: Can you show your current .htaccess?

Comment: Sure @anubhava, I'm not sure what I need to censor so hopefully it's still useful:

AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile *****
AuthName "Testing"
require valid-user

Comment: It's not clear how you're serving up the mp3s. It's just a link to open in safari? If you paste in the URL into safari does it not prompt the user for a username/password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hoops that iOS goes through to play a music file are [interesting, to say the least](http://community.freepbx.org/t/ari-playback-issues-on-iphone-ipad/9313/10?u=miken32). Looking at a packet trace, the credentials are sent properly for the initial request of the file, but the subsequent partial requests do not have credentials. This is likely a bug in Safari; if you get a free developer account with Apple, you can [report the problem to them](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

HTTP authentication works this way: the browser makes a request for a resource; the server responds with "401 Authorization Needed" and includes a `WWW-Authenticate` header indicating the type of authentication — in your case, basic — and the "realm" which is just a way of grouping protected resources. The client re-requests the same resource, adding an `Authorization` header that contains the username and password — in the case of basic auth, it's just base 64 user:pass. Typically, the browser will cache these credentials and send them without being asked, for every subsequent request within the same realm.

Comment: I did some testing with Wireshark and the iOS simulator, and this appears to be the issue. The range requests are not sending the `Authorization` header and consequently the response is `401 Authorization Required`.

Comment: Thanks Miken32 & @Alexander, unfortunately I have no idea what those issues mean but I do have an apple account and will submit a bug. I assume then there isn't a work-around?

Comment: Apple bug report #19698212